# How to Solve IndexError with xPath

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

My apologies, I'm a beginner. I've been trying to get metadata from SEC's website. Here's the link - https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001403161&type=10&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=40

Let's just fetch the dates for now. I'm trying xPath but it's throwing up an IndexError. I checked the fetched html and it does seem to have the data.

My code:

```
from lxml import html
import requests


page = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001403161&type=10&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=40')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

date = tree.xpath('//*[@id="seriesDiv"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]')[0].text
print(date)
```

How do I get this to work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: `tree.xpath('//*[@id="seriesDiv"]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[4]')` returns an empty list. So when you are trying to access the element in position 0 with `[0]`, it'll naturally say the index value is out of range. Do you have to use xpath? Pandas would be easier

Comment: Thanks for answering, chitown88. We don't have to use xPath but that's all I know for now. Can you guide me with that Pandas script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about xpath, as that's how I would have wrote it. But if you don't have to exclusively use xpath, I would go the Pandas route as it parses the whole table, and you can call individual cells if needed:

`pd.read_html()` will return a list of dataframes (Ie, all the `<table>` tags in the html). You just need to call the table you want, which in this case is index position 2 (or the last of the 3 dataframes)

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001403161&type=10&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=40'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)
df = dfs[-1]
```

**Output:**
    print (df.to_string())

```
print (df.to_string())
   Filings                      Format                                        Description Filing Date    File/Film Number
0     10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2019-07-26   001-3397719978181
1     10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2019-04-26   001-3397719771802
2     10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2019-01-31   001-3397719556097
3     10-K  Documents Interactive Data  Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K I...  2018-11-16  001-33977181189947
4     10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2018-07-27   001-3397718974910
5     10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2018-04-27   001-3397718783872
6     10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2018-02-01   001-3397718567042
7     10-K  Documents Interactive Data  Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K I...  2017-11-17  001-33977171209440
8     10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2017-07-20   001-3397717974492
9     10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2017-04-21   001-3397717774258
10    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2017-02-02   001-3397717568413
11    10-K  Documents Interactive Data  Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K I...  2016-11-15  001-33977162000223
12    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2016-07-25  001-33977161782265
13    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2016-04-25  001-33977161589237
14    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2016-01-28  001-33977161369122
15    10-K  Documents Interactive Data  Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K I...  2015-11-20  001-33977151244628
16    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2015-07-23  001-33977151002526
17    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2015-04-30   001-3397715819049
18    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2015-01-29   001-3397715559143
19    10-K  Documents Interactive Data  Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K I...  2014-11-21  001-33977141240400
20    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2014-07-24   001-3397714991576
21    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2014-04-24   001-3397714781985
22    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2014-01-30   001-3397714558846
23    10-K  Documents Interactive Data  Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K I...  2013-11-22  001-33977131236561
24    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2013-07-24   001-3397713983884
25    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2013-05-01   001-3397713803519
26    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2013-02-06   001-3397713578037
27    10-K  Documents Interactive Data  Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K I...  2012-11-16  001-33977121209935
28    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2012-07-27   001-3397712990778
29    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2012-05-02   001-3397712805918
30    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2012-02-08   001-3397712582250
31    10-K  Documents Interactive Data  Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K I...  2011-11-18  001-33977111214519
32    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2011-07-29   001-3397711996223
33    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2011-05-05   001-3397711815087
34    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2011-02-02   001-3397711566916
35    10-K  Documents Interactive Data  Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K I...  2010-11-19  001-33977101205707
36    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2010-08-02   001-3397710982428
37    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2010-05-03   001-3397710789509
38    10-Q  Documents Interactive Data  Quarterly report [Sections 13 or 15(d)]Acc-no:...  2010-02-03   001-3397710571090
39    10-K  Documents Interactive Data  Annual report [Section 13 and 15(d), not S-K I...  2009-11-20  001-33977091198831
```

To print an individual row and column:

```
print (df.loc[0,'Filing Date'])
2019-07-26
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach will return the whole column - filing data as a list,

```
    page = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001403161&type=10&dateb=&owner=exclude&count=40')
    tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

    Firstdate = tree.xpath('//table[@class="tableFile2"]//tr[2]/td[4]/text()')
    print(Fristdate)
    Alldates = tree.xpath('//table[@class="tableFile2"]//tr/td[4]/text()')

    print(Alldates)
```

**Output:**
['2019-07-26', '2019-04-26', '2019-01-31', '2018-11-16', '2018-07-27', '2018-04-27', '2018-02-01', '2017-11-17', '2017-07-20', '2017-04-21', '2017-02-02', '2016-11-15', '2016-07-25', '2016-04-25', '2016-01-28', '2015-11-20', '2015-07-23', '2015-04-30', '2015-01-29', '2014-11-21', '2014-07-24', '2014-04-24', '2014-01-30', '2013-11-22', '2013-07-24', '2013-05-01', '2013-02-06', '2012-11-16', '2012-07-27', '2012-05-02', '2012-02-08', '2011-11-18', '2011-07-29', '2011-05-05', '2011-02-02', '2010-11-19', '2010-08-02', '2010-05-03', '2010-02-03', '2009-11-20']